Given the graph of induced current, what is the formula for the magnetic field strength?

I'm from Norway, so I am sorry if I am translating some terms incorrectly. We had a big physics test, and there was this one problem I got correctly, but I am unsure of why it is correct. I tried asking my teacher, but both me and him are sceptical of his reasoning.
The problem is:
A coil has N windings and a cross section area A. The coil rotates around in a magnetic field. The graph below shows the induced current in the coil as a function of time. Which of the following expressions can be used to calculate the magnetic field strength?
I don't think the graph and the options are different in english. As you can see, B was the right option.
My teacher found a formula for the induced current, and took the derivative of it. I am sceptical of it, because I don't see how you end up with Wb on top. I would agree if the derivative of induced current has the unit of Wb, but I don't think this is the case. I think the unit would be V/s.
I would take the integral of the formula that my teacher found, because the derivative of the magnetic flux gives the induced current, but then I get wrong numbers.
How do you get the formula in option B?

Would like to start by clarifying that the graph given is of induced EMF and not of induced current. The next few formulas would hopefully explain the units.
As per Faraday's Laws of Electromagnetic induction,
$$
\epsilon = N\frac{-d\phi}{dt}
$$
where N is the number of turns, $ \phi $ is the magnetic flux passing through the coil which is given by
$$ \phi = \vec{B}.\vec{A}$$
The dot product simplifies to $\phi$ = BAcos($\theta$).
I leave it as an exercise for you to analyze how the angle between $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{A}$ varies with time as $\theta$=$\omega$t.
To find magnitude of magnetic field, find $\epsilon_{max}$ using the graph and compare it with the maximum value of $\epsilon$ you will get after substituting the required values in the first equation. One unknown is $\omega$ which will be the frequency of the rotation or the frequency of the sin curve which you can find using the graph.  Hope I could help!
